# How to publish iOS app for Zambia country from app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am not able to see the Zambia in territory list while publishing the all from app store. How can I make accessible my app to Zambian people

Answer (score 0):

Not all countries in the world have their own App Store territory. You can find the most current list in the official docs here: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev997f9cf7c

There currently is no territory called "Zambia".

Comment: Thanks for answer @Max but my concern is zambia people are using IPhone devices and they are able to download other apps. As a developer how can I make available my app to zambia people

Answer (score 0):

"**Zambia**" territory is not available in the list, But if you want to allow access to some specific territory then you can do using the following steps.

Goto iTunes Account -> Select "**MyApps**" -> select your app -> tap on "**App Store**" tab -> Select "**Pricing and Availability**" -> select price first as 0(zero) OR as you wish (then enable option to select territory) -> scroll down to **Availability** click on "**Edit**". (then select territory and save it)

[image]

Comment: Hello AtulPramar, I have a question zambia people are able to download other apps like whatsup ... so how whatsup is available for them. I also want to make available my app to zambia people how can I achieve this.

Comment: If you have all territories enabled, I'm sure it will be available there. (Top most checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2020, App Store expanded to an additional 2 regions including Zambia. You can read more from the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03232020a)